# Problema de sesion con Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Soy nuevo con Vue.js y
Tengo un problema al iniciar sesion en una aplicación, estaba funcionando bien y de un momento a otro ya no.
la parte de código donde me marca error es la siguiente:

me dice que la propiedad "response.estado" no puede ser leída ó es indefinida.

```
.then (function(response) { 
        vthis.autenticando = false;
        if(response!== null && response.estado == ''){
          vthis.msj = 'Credenciales invalidas.';
          vthis.dismissCountDown = vthis.dismissSecs;
        }else if(response!== null && response.estado == 'ACTIVO'){          
          vthis.$v_session.set('username',response.nombre)
          vthis.$v_session.set('info',JSON.stringify(response.info))
          /* Redireccionamos al Dashboard */
          vthis.$router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });
        }else if(response!== null && response.estado != 'ACTIVO'){
          vthis.msj = 'El usuario no se encuenta <b>activo</b>.';
          vthis.dismissCountDown = vthis.dismissSecs;
        }else{
          vthis.msj = 'Credenciales invalidas.';
          vthis.dismissCountDown = vthis.dismissSecs;
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: lo que me muestra el navegador]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias, Cualquier sugerencia es recibida.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! te esta dando un error de red antes de ese que marcas.. sera ese el problema?

Comment: imprime el valor de response

Comment: Usa [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) para que `this` tenga el scope fuera de la función `then`. En tu caso sería `.then(response => {...})`